# How to output an integer from another method via Console.WriteLine()?

Tags: c#, class, methods

So, I have a method where I set a date and store it in a variable called gameTime. That works. But now I created another method where I want to show that variable in the console and wrote **Console.WriteLine(gameTime);** but this is not accepted. It says, it does not excist in the current context. What do I need to do to make that accessable in the other method? Here is the code...

```
public class TimeSimulation
{
    public int Second { get; set; }
    public int Minute { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }



    public static void TimeSettings()
    {
        TimeSimulation startTime = new TimeSimulation();
        startTime.Second = 1;
        startTime.Minute = 1;
        startTime.Hour = 1;
        startTime.Day = 1;
        startTime.Month = 1;
        startTime.Year = 2000;

        DateTime gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
    }

    public static void ShowTime()
    {
        //DateTime gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
        Console.WriteLine(gameTime);
    }
```

Comment: add a property in your class like : `public DateTime gameTime {get;set;}` or add parameter to your method `ShowTime` like :`public static void ShowTime(DateTime gameTime)
    {........`

Comment: gameTime is not knowing to ShowTime method as it was commented out. And you need to print gameTime which was set in TimeSettings method. So create a property or a class level variable and assign the value from TimeSettings method then call it from ShowTime method. Check out my answer.

Comment: What is `gameTime` supposed to represent? Why is `TimeSettings()` static?

Comment: gameTime should contain time and date and I want to show this, manipulate it with AddDays() later on. So, maybe if I understand the whole concept of time simulation, I want to show it in an UI in the future, where the user can press play and the time will move on with one day steps. In case I gain more experience, I might even want to manipulate the speed via timer, but that's a bit too much for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TimeSimulation
{
    public int Second { get; set; }
    public int Minute { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    private static DateTime gameTime; 



    public static void TimeSettings()
    {
        TimeSimulation startTime = new TimeSimulation();
        startTime.Second = 1;
        startTime.Minute = 1;
        startTime.Hour = 1;
        startTime.Day = 1;
        startTime.Month = 1;
        startTime.Year = 2000;

        gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month,   startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
    }

    public static void ShowTime()
    {
        //DateTime gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
        Console.WriteLine(gameTime);
    }
}
```

This should work now as "gameTime" is now a class level variable rather than created inside TimeSettings method.

Hope you make sure that you will be calling ShowTime after TimeSettings method.

FYI - This is not related to the concept of the question, but would like to tell that the naming convention for TimeSettings method is not correct. I prefer to change it to "SetTimings()" or "InitializeTimings()".

Comment: Would like to know why it was downvoted? Is there any mistake in the answer.

Comment: I have updated my code to static variable instead of instance type. Sorry was done with overlook.

Comment: I am starting to wonder if what I tried to do is way too complex for what I want to achieve. I think the complexity started when someone at Reddit told me that I should create an own class for time simulation if I try to create a small and very simple business game. I am beginner, and I basically just want to be able to set a start date, and maybe later play this time forward with AddDays(). Then I guess that I will need another class where some things will go on, such as the players gets 1$ each day.

Comment: Was it expected answer?

Comment: I got an output as 1/1/2000 1:01:01 AM

Comment: That's not happening in my case. Is it because I call it from another class with: TimeSimulation.ShowTime(); ?

Comment: Even I called it from my program class as below, check it out how you are calling in your case,

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimeSimulation.TimeSettings();
            TimeSimulation.ShowTime();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

Comment: Thanks! That's working! I didn't do  TimeSimulation.TimeSettings();

Comment: Great, like to see if you can upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Sadly I still can't upvote you as a new user. But I am very thankful. But all this showed me that I still don't completely understand methods and classes. Looks like I should go back and watch some tutorials :)

Comment: Not a problem. You can learn basics about OOPs from this link http://www.programcall.com/ and watch KudVenkat from YouTube channel at this link https://www.youtube.com/user/kudvenkat

Comment: I'll take a look now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because your variable `gameTime` only exists in the `TimeSettings` method.

Try taking it outside the method and declare it as a field like this:

```
DateTime gameTime;

public static void TimeSettings()
{
    TimeSimulation startTime = new TimeSimulation();
    startTime.Second = 1;
    startTime.Minute = 1;
    startTime.Hour = 1;
    startTime.Day = 1;
    startTime.Month = 1;
    startTime.Year = 2000;

    DateTime gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
}

public static void ShowTime()
{
    //DateTime gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, 
    if(gameTime != null)
    {
        startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
        Console.WriteLine(gameTime);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:
My guess is that there is a misplaced bracket somewhere because you're creating another instance of your `TimeSimulation` class from within itself..

```
public class TimeSimulation
{
    public int Second { get; set; }
    public int Minute { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
} // I think this bracket was missing..

static DateTime gameTime;

public static void TimeSettings()
{
    TimeSimulation startTime = new TimeSimulation();
    startTime.Second = 1;
    startTime.Minute = 1;
    startTime.Hour = 1;
    startTime.Day = 1;
    startTime.Month = 1;
    startTime.Year = 2000;

    gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
}

public static void ShowTime()
{
    //DateTime gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, 
    if(gameTime != null)
    {
        startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
        Console.WriteLine(gameTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: yup.. I saw that one a bit too late :(

Comment: OK I see I must learn more about methods.... so, I should remove the static keyword?

Comment: @Dennis, That depends on the rest of your code. if these methods are within a static class than you can't just remove the static keywords. Have a look at [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/static) tutorial

Comment: Thanks for adding informations. No the class is public. But anyway, it's better I go through some more tutorials, I start with your link. I am still quite overwhelmed with all this :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you created `gameTime` within your first method, so it is only accessable within those scopes ( the `{` and `}` ).
If you want to access it from `ShowTime()` you have to put it outside of the scopes. You can do it like this :

```
public static DateTime gameTime { get; set; }
public void TimeSettings()
{
    TimeSimulation startTime = new TimeSimulation();
    startTime.Second = 1;
    startTime.Minute = 1;
    startTime.Hour = 1;
    startTime.Day = 1;
    startTime.Month = 1;
    startTime.Year = 2000;

    gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
}

public void ShowTime()
{
    //DateTime gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
    Console.WriteLine(gameTime);
}
```

Note that your methods can't be static this way. If they have to be, you can call gameTime like this:

`CLASSNAME.gameTime`

Answer (score 0):

You must to return value in your function when you want to use it in another

```
public static DateTime TimeSettings()
{
    TimeSimulation startTime = new TimeSimulation();
    startTime.Second = 1;
    startTime.Minute = 1;
    startTime.Hour = 1;
    startTime.Day = 1;
    startTime.Month = 1;
    startTime.Year = 2000;

    return gameTime = new DateTime(startTime.Year, startTime.Month, startTime.Day, startTime.Hour, startTime.Minute, startTime.Second);
}

public static void ShowTime()
{
    DateTime gameTime = TimeSettings()
    Console.WriteLine(gameTime);
}
```